# how to use java in xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

how to use java in xslt and avoid below errors:

> Cannot find a 1-argument function named
>   {java:com.poc.XSDDateTimeFormatter}toXSD(). Reflexive calls to Java
>   methods are not available under Saxon-HE and Cannot find a 2-argument
>   function named
>   {urn:java:com.poc.NLDataUnitTestTimeCalc}computeTestTime(). Reflexive
>   calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE

`computeTestTime` method of `NLDataUnitTestTimeCalc` class

```
public static long computeTestTime( String startDateStr, String endDateStr) {

  long testTime= 0;
  long longStartDate= 0;
  long longEndDate= 0; 

  for( String format: formats) {
     try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

        Date startdate = formatter.parse(startDateStr);
        Date enddate = formatter.parse(endDateStr);
        longStartDate=startdate.getTime();
        longEndDate=enddate.getTime();
        testTime = (Math.abs(longEndDate-longStartDate)/1000);
        break; 
     }
     catch (ParseException ex) {
        //ignore
     }
  }
  return testTime;
```

}

```
toXSD method of XSDDateTimeFormatter class

public static String toXSD( String dateStr) {
  for( String format: formats) {
     try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat( format).parse( dateStr);
        String xsd = new SimpleDateFormat( XSDdateTimeFormat).format( date);

        //special case for xsd:dateTime timezone format
        return 
                xsd.substring(0, xsd.length() - 2) + 
                ':' +
                xsd.substring(xsd.length() - 2);
     } catch (ParseException ex) {
        //ignore
     }
  }

  return dateStr;   }
```

### xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/Event">

        <bus:Timestamp> 
          <xsl:value-of                   xmlns:XSDDateTimeFormatter="java:com.amd.pde.integration.XSDDateTimeFormatter"
              select="XSDDateTimeFormatter:toXSD( //TimeStamp)"
           />   
        </bus:Timestamp>
```

### sample xml

```
<Event>   
<Message>BEGINEXECUTION</Message>
<TimeStamp>20080111000419146</TimeStamp>
<EquipmentID>stack</EquipmentID>
</Event>
```

Comment: let me know how to resolve the issue
Working example for the same will be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you use Saxon-HE, but extension functions in Java are only supported by Saxon-PE and Saxon-EE. The [Saxon-Docs](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/extensibility/functions/) mention this explicitly.

I guess you have two options

- Buy Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE
- Implement your functions in XSL

Comment: I did not find any dependency either for Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. You don't have Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE available, but Saxon-HE (the free edition). But the free edition cannot call Java functions from XSL. For this you **need** one of the two paid editions. This is what Saxon says in the error message.

Comment: There are three options I think, the third being that you can write the extension function code as integrated extension functions http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/ and that way can make use of Java.

Comment: I wonder if the XSDDateTimeFormatter is really doing anything that can't be done using the standard format-dateTime() function in XSLT 2.0/3.0?

Comment: @Michael Kay - preserving the value from input xml if its not parsable to date is the challenge

Comment: That sounds like `if ($x castable as xs:dateTime) then format-dateTime(xs:dateTime($x)) else $x`.

Comment: yes @MichaelKay .
I am new to xml .so can you please let me know how to do this

Comment: Well, he literally did in his last comment. Try do it by yourself, begin small, let it grow and ask here on stack overflow specific questions if you are stuck. Don't ask for complete solutions.